# Failed to create AVD from command line; message says java.se.ee not found

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create AVD on my mac from command line,

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
```

Then I got this error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
>       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>       at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
>       at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       ... 5 more

I tried to fix the problem by doing

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

And then the error message become

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

It seems java.se.ee was removed in JAVA 11 but now I am using JAVA 13. Is there any solution other than downgrade JAVA version?

Answer (score 0):

At last I downgrade my java to 8 and it worked.